# Feature request: Unmark comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Just like you can upvote a question or answer and then undo that, can this be possible for comments as well? It would be nice to be able to retract a marked comment.

Comment: +1 Believe it or not, I have sometimes *accidentally* marked a comment.  I know everyone's going to say such could be avoided by being more careful, but I see no point in forcing the issue.  We have a 5-min grace period with post-votes, don't we?

Comment: This is a request for unmarking comments made from the user Mark. I guess the user Unmark would make a request to mark a comment for a specific reason. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

This was asked on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) and has a score of 233, and the five answers all support it (with a combined score of 342) along with all the comments, but still the feature request was declined for unknown reasons.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/149375) ont he meta.SO thread clarifies things. You can now un-upvote a comment if you do it within a minute.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in meta.stackoverflow (in [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/165524) to the question Hugo mentioned) an un-upvote-comment feature (to retract or revert an upvote on a comment) was added in April, 2012.

Some restrictions apply:  Your upvote is locked in if you navigate away from the page with the comment, or if 60 seconds go by.   You can upvote a comment at most once.

Comment: Feel free to mark this comment, if you'd like, and then unmark it within 60 seconds. (I'm pretty sure some will want to test this).

Comment: Wow! Your hypnotically mesmerising comment is even more compulsive than [the big red button!](http://www.i-am-bored.com/bored_link.cfm?link_id=9644) (which I've successfully resisted pressing for nearly two minutes now! :) Sadly though, it seems I'll never be able to upvote your comment again in future, having just "un-upvoted" it once as a test.